# layout_below in relative layout won't show

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to make a layout_below the cardview in relative layout but it wont show up in my device where layout_above works. i dont know why it wont work. i think it should be work because it below the cardview. please help what did i miss or wrong.

this is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_2"
    tools:context=".ExchangeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/saldo"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/holder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Will Stitch"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/saldo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Saldo"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/saldo"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="WillStitch@gmail.com"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please help why it like this

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you share a screenshot? seems like you didn't add the `android:src` attribute to the `ImageView` below, is this on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working but your `ImageView` take all the width and it don't have `android:src` attribute (so it show nothing) and you don't need the last LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/saldo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Useless Linear Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="WillStitch@gmail.com"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```